# In an unit test for an LWC, how can I mock out a fetch to a third party API?

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, api, lwc-jest, mock

I have a Lightning Web Component with the following HTML:

```
<template>
     <h1>Current price of a bitcoin in Euro</h1>
     <lightning-formatted-number currency-code="EUR"
                            format-style="currency"
                            value={euroPrice}
     ></lightning-formatted-number>
</template>
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
    import {LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';

const bitcoinPriceProvider = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=EUR';
export default class BitcoinEuroPrice extends LightningElement {
    @api
    refreshRateInSeconds;

    @track
    euroPrice;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.fetchPrice();
        setInterval(this.fetchPrice, this.refreshRateInSeconds * 1000);
    }

    fetchPrice() {
        fetch(bitcoinPriceProvider)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.euroPrice = json.data.amount;
            });
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a Jest test for it, but the test fails when I try to mock out the `fetch` operation:

This is the test:

```
import {createElement} from 'lwc';
```

import BitcoinEuroPrice from 'c/bitcoinEuroPrice';

describe('c-bitcoinEuroPrice', () => {
afterEach(() => {
while (document.body.firstChild) {
document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
}
});

```
it('fetches price', () => {
    // Arrange
    const testAmount = '8448.947391885';
    const mockApiResponse = {
        'data': {
            'base': 'BTC',
            'currency': 'EUR',
            'amount': testAmount
        }
    };
    fetch = global.fetch = mockFetch(mockApiResponse);

    // Act
    const priceUnderTest = createElement('c-bitcoinEuroPrice', {
        is: BitcoinEuroPrice
    });
    console.log('######## priceUnderTest', priceUnderTest);

    // Assert
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=EUR');
    expect(priceUnderTest.euroPrice).toEqual(testAmount);
});

function mockFetch(mockApiResponse) {
    return jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce(() =>
            Promise.resolve({
                ok: true,
                json: () => Promise.resolve(mockApiResponse),
                jsonResponse: mockApiResponse
            })
        );
}
```

});

and this is the error:

> FAIL
> force-app/main/default/lwc/bitcoinEuroPrice/**tests**/bitcoinEuroPriceTest.js
> c-bitcoinEuroPrice
> × fetches price (32ms)
>
> ● c-bitcoinEuroPrice › fetches price
>
> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)
>
> Expected number of calls: 1
> Received number of calls: 0
>
>   28 | 
>   29 |         // Assert
> > 30 |         expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
>      |         ^
>   31 |         expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=EUR');
>   32 |         expect(priceUnderTest.euroPrice).toEqual(testAmount);
>   33 |     });
> ```

```
    ^
```

Any idea how I can mock out or spy on`fetch` successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the problem was that I needed to connect the element to execute the `connectedCallback`.

(Duh!!!)

e.g.:

```
        // Act
        const priceUnderTest = createElement('c-bitcoinEuroPrice', {
            is: BitcoinEuroPrice
        });
        document.body.appendChild(priceUnderTest);
```